# find angle in triangle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Let us consider problem number 21 in  the following link

http://www.naec.ge/images/doc/EXAMS/math_2013_ver_1_web.pdf

It is from georgian national exam, it is written (ამოცანა 21), where word "ამოცანა" means amocana or problem. We should find angle $\angle ADE$. I have calculated angle $B$, which is equal to $87^\circ$, but is there any sign of similarity between these two triangle or how can I find it? I think I could calculate angle using arc formula, but I don't remember exactly how it is, even how can I connect arc's angle and $\angle ADE$ angle together? Please help me.

Comment: I think that should be $87^\circ$ for angle $\angle ABC$.

Comment: aa yes yes  right 87

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- A convex quadrilateral BCDE is cyclic if and only if its opposite angles sum up to $180^\circ$.

See also the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral).

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: so it means that  angle EDC is equal to $180-87=93$ and  angle  ADE is equal to $87$?

Comment: @dato So it seems ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say $\widehat{ED}=\alpha$ and $\widehat{BC}=\beta$. We know that $36=\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}$. And also $\widehat{EDC}=174^\circ$. So we have $\widehat{EB}=114-\alpha$. Hence $\widehat{EBC}=114+\beta-\alpha$, i.e.$\widehat{EBC}=114+72=186^\circ$. Thus, $\angle EDC=93^\circ$ and $\angle EDC=87^\circ$.